# Pointer to Array holding two Vectors

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, vector

I am having something i can't seem to figure out myself again. I don't know how to call this problem.

```
vector<int> *integerVectors[2] = { new vector<int>, new vector<int>};
(*integerVectors)[0].push_back(1);
(*integerVectors)[1].push_back(1);
```

When i run this i get an unhandled exeption. What I want is an Array with 2 indexes and each of them holding a vector.

EDIT: The Problem seems to appear when i start pushing back.

Comment: Do not do that. Use `vector<int> integerVectors[2]; integerVectors[0].push_back(1);` Simple, yes?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

this syntax:

```
MyType *var[size];
```

creates an array of pointers to `MyType` of size `size`, which means that this:

```
vector<int> *integerVectors[2];
```

produces a size 2 array of pointers to integer vectors, a fact which is backed up by your ability to initialize `integerVectors` with an initializer-list of pointers to integer vectors produced by calls to `new`.

this:

```
(*integerVectors)
```

produces a pointer to your first vector pointer. You then call operator[] on it, which offsets the pointer by the size of a vector. But this is no longer a pointer to your array--if you call it with an argument of greater than 0, you'll be referencing an imaginary vector next to the one pointed by your first vector element.

Then you call `push_back` on the imaginary vector, naturally leading to massive problems at run time.

You either want to offset before dereferencing, as in @Abstraction's suggestion of

```
integerVectors[i]->push_back(1);
```

or you want to avoid C-style arrays. You're already using one vector, and nesting them rather than making arrays of them will avoid much confusion of this type in the future, while preserving the correct syntax:

```
vector<vector<int>*> integerVectors = {new vector<int>, new vector<int>};
integerVectors[1]->push_back(1);
```

Without the c-style array, your needed syntax is vastly clearer.

Even better, you could just avoid the pointers altogether and use

```
vector<vector<int>> integerVectors = {vector<int>{}, vector<int>{}};
integerVectors[1].push_back(1);
```

The first line of which has a few equivalent syntaxes, as pointed out by @NeilKirk:

```
vector<vector<int>> integerVectors(2);
vector<vector<int>> integerVectors{{},{}};
vector<vector<int>> integerVectors(2, vector<int>{});
vector<vector<int>> integerVectors(2, {});
```

The curly braces I'm using in initialization are another way to initialize an object, without the possibility of the compiler confusing it for a function in the most vexing parse. (However, you have to be careful with it around things which can be initialized with initializer lists like here, which is why some of these initializations use parentheses, instead) The first syntax default-initializes two vectors, and so does the second, though it explicitly states the same thing. It can also be modified to produce more complex structures: two vectors both with the elements {1,2,3} could be one of the below:

```
vector<vector<int>> integerVectors = {{1,2,3},{1,2,3}};
vector<vector<int>> integerVectors{{1,2,3},{1,2,3}};
vector<vector<int>> integerVectors(2, vector<int>{1,2,3});
vector<vector<int>> integerVectors(2, {1,2,3});
```

Comment: The final pointer-less example has an initialization with wrong types. You want `vector<vector<int>> integerVectors{ 2 }` to get two default-constructed `vector<int>`s.

Comment: @NeilKirk Fixed. Thanks. Alas, for I am betrayed by copy-paste! /s

Comment: Why not `vector<vector<int>> integerVectors(2);`

Comment: This is incredible! This was extremly helpful!

Answer (score 2):

This line is the problem

```
(*integerVectors)[1].push_back(1);
```

Dereferencing `*integerVectors` gives you the first vector pointer (equivalent of `integerVectors[0]`. Then you call you call operator[] with `1` as arguent on this pointer which will give reference to vector with address shifted with one vector size forward (equivalent to `*(integerVectors[0]+1)` ) which is not valid.
The right syntax is

```
 integerVectors[1]->push_back(1);
```

Comment: You are right I am sorry I forgot that it is array of pointers. I corrected the answer.